# Как через код php добавлять строку перед текстом не удаляя других символов?

Tags: php, файлы

Делаю так, чтоб создавалась строка перед текстом:

```
$won = $prise * 0.8;
$notifications_users = fopen("logs/users/$id_c.txt", "c+t");
fwrite($notifications_users, "Join to lottery with prise $won!");
fclose($notifications_users);
```

и так несколько раз, потом вывожу посточно сообщения:

```
$fileo = fopen("logs/users/$id_ad.txt", "r+t");
$id_ad = $accessed['id'];
while(!feof($fileo)){
    $fread = fgets($fileo, 99);
    echo "<div>$fread</div>";
}
```

и каждый раз символы строки заменяються и в итоге выводит только одну строку.. я понимаю, все из-за мода "c" но есть возможность дописать в начале текста не удалив символы?

Comment: вы лучше напишите, что вы сделать хотите. что у вас есть в файле, и что вы хотите получить в итоге

Comment: @teran, я делаю popover с оповещениями, и в нем сверху вниз по порядку должны выводиться оповещения в блоках с текстового документа по строке, как в коде, но когда прийдет новое сообщение оно должно оказаться в верху списка (в начале текстового документа)

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
$popover = "Join to lottery with prise $won!" . PHP_EOL;
$popover .= file_get_contents('logs/users/$id_c.txt');
file_put_contents('logs/users/$id_c.txt', $popover);
```

Тут к требуемой строке добавляется содержимое файла, а потом все это записывается в файл обратно.